# Why does tensorflow uses reduce_* in reduce_max, reduce_min, reduce_sum etc?

Tags: tensorflow, naming-conventions

I always try to find the semantics associated with the function names, because that really helps to understand and hook up things.

I am just trying to understand why Google came up with reduce_* naming convention for methods like:

- reduce_all
- reduce_any
- reduce_join
- reduce_logsumexp
- reduce_max
- reduce_mean
- reduce_min
- reduce_prod
- reduce_sum

Is it because all these operations reduce the dimension of the input tensor?

Comment: I think they regretted using these names and so they changed them in the latest version of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reduce` is just a name for a family of operations which are used to create a single object from the sequence of objects, repeatedly applying the same binary operation.

For example, a summation of an array could be viewed as an application of `+` operation for the first two elements of the sequence, then the summation of the result and the third element and so on. This gives a sum of the whole array. So, `sum(1, 2, 3, 4)` could be computed as `(((1 + 2) + 3) + 4)`. This implementation of the reduce is computationally inefficient since all is computed sequentially, so tensorflow (and other software) uses parallel reduce instead (where sum(1, 2, 3, 4) is computed rather like  (1 + 2) + (3 + 4)), but this is just details.